# Refer to a cell in another worksheet by referencing the current sheet's name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have looked into the already asked questions, yet I could not find a way to achieve my objective.

I have 5 sheets in excel named as:

> 1. Roll Number
> 2. Names
> 3. Pay Slips
> 4. Date of Birth
> 5. DOJ

I want to put the data in the 'Names' sheet referencing a cell with the names of other sheet and get data from cell 'U3' from other sheets.

I have tried using `=Indirect` function, but haven't got far enough.

For DOJ it works well using

`=Indirect(D4&"!U3")`

- Where D4 holds DOJ.
- D1 holds Roll Number
- D2 holds Pay Slips
- D3 holds Date of Birth
- D4 holds DOJ

All these are in sheet 'Names'

However, whenever i use `=Indirect(D1&"!U3")` it gives a `#REF` error.

I want to do this using a formula and not VBA.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sheet names containing spaces, enclose the name in`'`

```
=Indirect("'"&D1&"'!U3")
```

Comment: Check your sheets names for leading/training spaces.